# Excel: Finding matching criteria from 2 distinct columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm analyzing some data for a program that I'm currently in. Sorry if the question is vague, but bear with me.

I'm trying to analyze the contents/criteria of column B "rideable_type" and column M "member_casual", indicated by the black squares.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is this: I'm trying to figure out if there is a correlation between the bikes that people ride, and the member affiliation that they identify with. An easier way to explain this could be: "Do members ride classic_bikes more than electric bikes? In other words, does member affiliation correlate to the type of bikes that they ride?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome on SO. You can use COUNTIFS function to count different couple. So the max value is the choice. See this example: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/countif-multiple-criteria-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try Pivot table, to present them in more powerful way, and more dimensions too:

[image]